# Estimation of a sum

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I want to show this sum converges to $ 0 $ , when  $n $ tends to infinity :

$\frac { 1 } { 2 ^{n^2}}\sum _{m> \frac {n^2} {2} + cn\sqrt { n}}      { {n ^2}\choose{m}}$

Is this claim true?

How to show it?

Thanks.

Comment: own thoughts?...

Comment: You may appeal to the Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: @SangchulLee oh right!if I define  $Y $ as sum of $n^2$  0-1 Bernoulli variables   ,I get $P (|Y-n^2/2|> c n \sqrt n ) < P (Y-n^2/2|> tn/2)<1/t^2$,so that sum converges to zero. Thanks!